# Is this a valid proof that this statement is incorrect?

Tags: limits, solution-verification, maxima-minima

Please take a look below :
[image]
Am I making some mistake with my proof?

Comment: Change "$g(x) \geq f(x)$... " to "$g(x) > f(x)$... "

Comment: $g(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} g(x)$ looks a strange thing to say rather than $g(x)=0$.  And I do not know what "existential proof" means, so I would have said "counter-example".   The key point your proof makes is there need not be an *open* interval with $f(x)=\max(f(x),g(x))$ so "open" might be worth adding. As @DavidPerrella says with a typo, you need to write $g(x)>f(x)$ rather than $g(x)\ge f(x)$ when $x\not=0$.

Comment: Please don't use images to contain the content of your post—it messes up the search functionality and prevents helpful edits, among other things.